# Unable to grab first capturing group - Matcher find() showing empty

Tags: java, regex

```
String response = "{\"phone\":[{\"firstName\":\"sandeepan\",\"lastName\":\"\"}]}";
System.out.println("response "+response);
        Pattern ps = Pattern.compile("/\\{\"\\.\\*\"firstName\":\"([a-z]*)\"\\.\\*/");
        Matcher m = ps.matcher(response);
        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println("matched "+m.group());
        }
        System.out.println("After matching block");
```

Output:

```
response {"phone":[{"firstName":"sandeepan","lastName":""}]}
After matching block
```

The regex is working though - https://regex101.com/r/L2vZ9J/1/

Why we are using regex instead of json parsing:

- There could be multiple sets of data in the response against a given phone number and we are fine with grabbing the first one.
- There is a value in the first attribute ("phone" is a value and not a key, so need to model it as a class it seems, to do it properly.)

This is just a one time task, so we need to get it done quickly - there is not much implementation time.

Comment: Why would you use regex to parse JSON?

Comment: There could be multiple sets of data in the response against a given phone number and this is just a one time task, so we need to get it done quickly - not much implementation time is there.

Comment: Remove the `/`  at the start and end. Actually, your regex in Java is not the same as in the regex tester. You overescaped the pattern.

Comment: Really confused with the escaping. Could you please guide what should be my pattern after escaping?

Comment: All you need is `Pattern.compile("\"firstName\":\"([^\"]*)\"")` and `m.group(1)`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot